# Do I need to constantly sign in to github when using terminal?

Tags: github, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to github, I created an account and uploaded my first project using the terminal on ubuntu. When I tried to add something for the first time it asked me to sign in. My question is will I have to sign in every time I add/commit files to github. Does installing github on ubuntu allow the computer to remember that it is me so I don't have to always sign in through the terminal?

Comment: To not ask for the password you must use the option to link using an ssh key.

Comment: read this: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign in in one way or another every time you push. Though you might manage to store passwords somewhere in plain text, the better approach would be to generate an ssh key and tell Github that you are using it to authenticate.

You can find a comprehensive instruction on how to do this [here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).

Answer (score 2):

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Check out this link. also consider setting up your connection to your account via SSH method.